# How do I select from a row having the maximum value in Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a gauge report built in SSRS that shows the weighted average and average of a data set returned from an SP.  In addition, I would like to show which row has the max/min values.  I can easily pull the max/min values but not the description to go along with that value.  Any ideas?

Comment: The current proc returns a data set of description, number of shots, and percent of volume.  I'd like to stick the description for the row having the lowest and highest percent of volume in a text box.

Comment: can you post your current query?  Otherwise it is just guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Poorly asked question as it really did not have anything to do with a query.  I ended up using the techniques from this blog,  http://www.bigator.com/2012/04/26/spothighlight-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-each-row-in-matrix-report-in-ssrs/